# Get Projects in Project Server 2013 using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, ms-project-server-2013, sharepoint-jsom

i would love to get the list of my projects from Project Server 2013 and displaying them on Sharepoint using Javascript.

Thx

Comment: did you try MSDN? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj668539.aspx

Comment: i used that but i couldn't find the data i needed (i found a solution later)

Answer (score 0):

If someone have the same need :)

```
$.ajax({       url: "https://Server/PWA/_api/ProjectServer/Projects?$select=Name",
               contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
               headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
               success: onSuccess,
               error: onFail,
           });

           function onSuccess(mydata, request) {
              ProjectNames = mydata.d.results;  
               };
        function onFail(errorObject, errorMessage) {
              $("#messages").text("Error: " + errorMessage + " - Status: " + errorObject.status.toString() + ", " + errorObject.statusText);
}
```